# Excessive whitespace around filepath

Tags: powershell-2.0

```
PS C:\> $pst_path = $outlook.Session.Stores | where { ($_.FilePath -like '*.PST') } | Select Filepath | format-table -hide
PS C:\> $pst_path

C:\Users\abelej\Documents\Outlook Files\My Outlook Data File(1).pst


PS C:\> _
```

I've tried using `$pst_path.trim()` method to trim leading and trailing spaces but with no luck.  You can see above all the white space the variable contains.  The problem comes up when I'm using `Copy-Item` which complains that the file name exceeds the 260 character limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Format-*` cmdlets are for displaying formatted data to the user. Do not use them if you need to further process your data. Simply expand the `FilePath` property instead:

```
$outlook.Session.Stores |
  where { $_.FilePath -like '*.PST' } |
  select -Expand FilePath
```

Comment: Ansgar, so simple...thank you, that worked!  I'm still learning powershell and sometimes forget the basics.